# Tensorflow Dividing a [X, 10, 10, 1] matrix by [X, 1]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to divide a [X, 10, 10, 1] matrix by the sum of each [10, 10, 1] matrix - so dividing [X, 10, 10, 1] by [X, 1] however using tf.broadcast_to gives an "incompatible shapes" error as shown directly below:

```
t1 = tf.ones([128, 10, 10, 1]) 
t1_sum = tf.reduce_sum(t1, [1, 2])  # Yields a [128, 1]
t1_sum_reshaped = tf.broadcast_to(t1_sum, (t1.shape))
divided = tf.math.divide(t1, t1_sum_reshaped)
```

Error w/ X=128 when using tf.broadcast_to: Incompatible shapes: [128,1] vs. [128,10,10,1] [Op:BroadcastTo]

My workaround to get division working is as follows, but it seems to be awfully slow (and dumb)

```
t1 = tf.ones([128, 10, 10, 1])
t1_sum = tf.reduce_sum(t1, [1, 2])                                                                            # Yields a [128, 1]
t1_sum = tf.stack([t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum], axis=-2)  # Yields a [128, 10, 1]
t1_sum = tf.stack([t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum, t1_sum], axis=-2)  # Yields a [128, 10, 10, 1]
divided = tf.math.divide(t1, t1_sum)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A small improvement can be `t1_sum = tf.stack([t1_sum for _ in range(t1.shape[-2])], axis=-2)` that is faster to write and works for different shapes rather than only 10. But still I feel like an even better solution is possible

Comment: Be sure to write down a test with pseudo-random data to make sure that other approaches give the same result as yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can add the keepdims=True argument to your code and it will work as intended:

```
t1 = tf.ones([128, 10, 10, 1])
t1_sum = tf.reduce_sum(t1, [1, 2], keepdims=True) # Yields a [128, 1, 1, 1]
t1_sum_reshaped = tf.broadcast_to(t1_sum, t1.shape)
divided = tf.math.divide(t1, t1_sum_reshaped)
```

After doing this you can remove the line `t1_sum_reshaped = tf.broadcast_to(t1_sum, t1.shape` since it already has the desired shape.

```
t1 = tf.ones([128, 10, 10, 1])
t1_sum = tf.reduce_sum(t1, [1, 2], keepdims=True) # Yields a [128, 1, 1, 1]
divided = tf.math.divide(t1, t1_sum)
```

Comment: You can skip the broadcast_to and do `divided = tf.math.divide(t1, t1_sum)` which will automatically do.

Comment: @V.M Absolutely... I added it to my answer.